# Can we access a reusable DaysOfWeek control?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile

Just wondering if we have access to the PocketOutlook DaysOfWeek control/editor, or if anybody else has made their own for free usage.

I'm looking for something exactly like what's in the Outlook Calendar appointment reoccurring pattern editor.

1. Open Calendar
2. Create a new Appointment
3. Click on "Occurs", then "< Edit Pattern... >"
4. Click "Next"
5. The control that has SMTWTFS, where you can tap on the square for the day to enable/disable, or use the hardware keys to navigate.

--UPDATE------------------------

Ah well, I just rolled my own Control.

Not too difficult, I just used 7 LinkLabels w/ click handlers.   Actually the hardest part was getting a border around it (using manual positioning to place the white linklabel just inside a black panel).   It's ridiculous that somehow the .NET CF designers thought that we wouldn't need BORDERS.

I exposed the DaysOfWeek value with a Value property, and a ValueChanged event.   Presto, a DaysOfWeek control!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code snippets for my homebrewed control:

```
public partial class DaysOfWeekPicker : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

    private DaysOfWeek myValue;

    [DefaultValue (0)]
    public DaysOfWeek Value
    {
        get { return myValue; }
        set { myValue = value; RefreshData (); }
    }

    public DaysOfWeekPicker ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    private void DayOfWeekClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals (sender, g_l_Sunday))
        {
            this.Value = this.Value ^ DaysOfWeek.Sunday;
        }
        else if (Object.ReferenceEquals (sender, g_l_Monday))
        {
            this.Value = this.Value ^ DaysOfWeek.Monday;
        }
        else if (Object.ReferenceEquals (sender, g_l_Tuesday))
        {
            this.Value = this.Value ^ DaysOfWeek.Tuesday;
        }
        else if (Object.ReferenceEquals (sender, g_l_Wednesday))
        {
            this.Value = this.Value ^ DaysOfWeek.Wednesday;
        }
        else if (Object.ReferenceEquals (sender, g_l_Thursday))
        {
            this.Value = this.Value ^ DaysOfWeek.Thursday;
        }
        else if (Object.ReferenceEquals (sender, g_l_Friday))
        {
            this.Value = this.Value ^ DaysOfWeek.Friday;
        }
        else if (Object.ReferenceEquals (sender, g_l_Saturday))
        {
            this.Value = this.Value ^ DaysOfWeek.Saturday;
        }
    }

    private void RefreshData ()
    {
        SetLabelDisplay (g_l_Sunday, (this.Value & DaysOfWeek.Sunday) == DaysOfWeek.Sunday);
        SetLabelDisplay (g_l_Monday, (this.Value & DaysOfWeek.Monday) == DaysOfWeek.Monday);
        SetLabelDisplay (g_l_Tuesday, (this.Value & DaysOfWeek.Tuesday) == DaysOfWeek.Tuesday);
        SetLabelDisplay (g_l_Wednesday, (this.Value & DaysOfWeek.Wednesday) == DaysOfWeek.Wednesday);
        SetLabelDisplay (g_l_Thursday, (this.Value & DaysOfWeek.Thursday) == DaysOfWeek.Thursday);
        SetLabelDisplay (g_l_Friday, (this.Value & DaysOfWeek.Friday) == DaysOfWeek.Friday);
        SetLabelDisplay (g_l_Saturday, (this.Value & DaysOfWeek.Saturday) == DaysOfWeek.Saturday);

        if (this.ValueChanged != null) this.ValueChanged (this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void SetLabelDisplay (LinkLabel label, bool enabled)
    {
        if (enabled)
        {
            label.BackColor = Color.Black;
            label.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            label.BackColor = Color.White;
            label.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

There may be a better way to do the value comparisons, but this is just what I came up with very quickly.

As far as the designer part of it goes, I won't put it in here because of its verbosity, but it's rather simple.   Each day is represented by a LinkLabel with the click event set to DayOfWeekClick.   Each LinkLabel is at (1,1) and is 2 pixels smaller in both dimensions from is parent Panel.   Each parent Panel has a black ForeColor, giving a border effect.   Each Panel is set to DockStyle.Left, and the overall control size is equivalent to panel.Width * 7, panel.Height.

Answer (score 1):

Those are just checkbox controls.